# Setting tab bar badge from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have an observer in my `AppDelegate` that I would like to use for showing badge numbers on a tab bar button when the client receives a new message. I can edit the badge from the `SampleViewController.m`'s `viewDidLoad` with this line `[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";`, but don't know how to set this from the `AppDelegate`. I tried to add the `UITabBarDelegate`, import `SampleViewController.h` and call `[[SampleViewController navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";` but didn't work. I also tried to implement a class method in `SampleViewController` that alters the badge number and call from the observer, but couldn't put `[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";` into a class method. Could somebody help me on how can I achieve this? I know I could put an observer into every VC, but it would be more elegant to do that from the AppDelegate.

```
AppDelegate.m

- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessage *)message {

   // DISPLAY A NUMBER IN THE TAB BAR BADGE WHEN THE CLIENT RECEIVES A MESSAGE

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.window.rootViewController` to get access to the root view controller of you view hierarchy. At that point, it's a matter of traversing that hierarchy to get a reference to the view controller you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass UITabBarController with a simple implementation.  Then you can still post a NSNotifcation, but only need one class to observe it. I just ran this test:

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self performSelector:@selector(notify) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    return YES;
}

-(void)notify{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"post" object:nil];
}

//additional implementation...
```

And your custom TabController

```
@implementation TabController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify) name:@"post" object:nil];
}

-(void)notify{
    UITabBarItem *item = self.tabBar.items[0];
    item.badgeValue = @"1";
}

@end
```

Obviously, don't use performSelector in your own AppDelegate.  I only did that so I could launch my test application, verify there was no badge on the tab bar, then after 5 seconds watch it update itself.  You should put your notification wherever is appropriate.